# How to set the localhost of the VM machine identical to the host computer?

Tags: localhost, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm using VM Virtual Box. When I run a server code in the VM and then I open the browser in the *host* machine and type "localhost", I don't get the page I get in the VM. Probably, localhost in the VM and in the host machine are different. Do you know how to make the localhost of the VM the same as the one of the host?

> dev@dev-VirtualBox:~$ ifconfig eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr
>   08:00:27:03:1a:e0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe03:1ae0/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:10813 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:3337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:11494848 (11.4 MB)  TX bytes:793819 (793.8 KB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
>             RX packets:2128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:2128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:192087 (192.0 KB)  TX bytes:192087 (192.0 KB)

Comment: I don't know how to make localhost of the guest the same as the one of the host, and even not sure that it's a good idea, but why can't you use the ip address of the VM?
Find ip of your guest: if it is linux, then in terminal `ip -4 addr show` and if windows then `ipconfig`. Use that address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is a special ip address 127.0.0.1 and it is the ip address of that computer on which you have physical access. To access localhost of another computer you MUST use the ip address of that computer...
Set your virtual machine network interface to bridged mode and under that choose your lan or wifi card for network  adapter. This way your virtual machine will get an ip address from your local network and you will be able to easily connect to that machine. If you need more information  or help. Send me a message with @lewis4u at the beginning

When you run this command

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

you must get exactly this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And open network settings in VirtualBox and under Advanced hit that refresh button a few times so you get new MAC address

[image]

And there is one more thing! Under Adapter type in VirtualBox you MUST have your host network adapter (LAN or WIFI) if you don't know how to find it ask me.

Comment: I changed "Attached to:" from "NAT" to "Bridged Adapter" and then internet connection to the VM stopped.

Comment: Forgot to say you need to change your mac address of your VM. Go to network settings/advanced and refresh mac address

Comment: I did it. Still, I don't have internet connection in the VM.

Comment: Can you run if config and make a Screenshot and put it in your question

Comment: OK i'm at my computer now...you are not getting connection from DHCP...i will update my answer